# Gare du Nord to Montparnasse walking tour

Tags: paris, children, walking

In August, I've got a 3.5 hour gap between arriving at Gare du Nord and my onward train from Montparnasse. I have two toddlers and would like to walk between the two stations. What are the best sights to see en route? Traditional sights are welcome, but also anything which is particularly toddler friendly.

Comment: This does not sound like a walk I'd have with toddlers. Did you check the distance? Do you have no luggage?

Comment: Luggage notwithstanding, this is (only?) a 5k walk. For a *toddler*, that's a lot, but perhaps these toddlers already know how to walk and thus aren't really toddlers?

Comment: [This is the journey according to google maps.](https://goo.gl/maps/tCbcr3zk9kP2) In between start and finish you have a couple parks (man I *hate* to call them `a couple parks`), the Opera, the Pompidou centre, the Louvre, the Pantheon, the Invalides, and the list goes on. Isn't this kinda broad?

Comment: 1 year old and 3 year old.. we will have a double buggy!

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account possible delays with childs walking speed and drink/food pause, here's a suggestion :

- Take subway from Gare du Nord to Etienne Marcel. Although it is a
  lively and populous area, it's the part that I would remove from the
  walking path in order to have more time on other parts.
- Walk to the Centre Pompidou, where depending on time of day you could
  see various street artist showing besides an outside view of the
  museum itself.
- Walk to Jardin du Luxembourg, walking thru Ile de la Cité. The Jardin
  du Luxembourg is a large public garden, where kids might rest and go
  a few playgrounds.
- Depending on how the kids are tired and the remaining time, either
  take the subway or bus from Luxembourg or walk to Montparnasse train
  station.

Comment: Mind that most of the grass in Jardin du Luxembourg is off-limits.

Comment: @mts Only during the winter (pelouse à repos), or am I mistaken?

Comment: @JoErNanO I remember being chased off the grass by the guards in plain summer. There was one area where it was allowed but you had to be searching to find more than a square foot of free space.

Comment: @mts [You are right.](http://www.senat.fr/visite/jardin/infos_pratiques.html) `accès aux pelouses de l'Observatoire autorisé au public (hors périodes de maintenance) ; autres pelouses interdites ;`